# Does C++ support member function references?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

C++ permits *function pointers* and [*function references*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480248/function-references). It also permits *pointers-to-member-functions*.

But **does it permit references-to-member-functions**?

I can't seem to deduce the rules from the standard, and I've failed to make a program work with them.

---

<sup>[ [member function pointers](http://www.ideone.com/C6oex) ] [ [member function references](http://www.ideone.com/D9tUI) ]</sup>

Comment: Apart from the intriguing aspect of it, Is there any practical application of this feature that you think this would be need?

Comment: @Als: If I wanted to use references rather than pointers.

Comment: I think it should be banned to answer your own questions.

Comment: @g24l: [Why's that?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions)

Comment: @g24: From the FAQ: "There are already numerous posts that answer their own questions. There's nothing wrong with it. It's even encouraged." (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463)

Comment: What's with the downvotes? This is a concise, specific question about a programming language.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: You can see why (you have donwvotes) in your own link [just scroll down an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/12514/138817)

Comment: I just don't like it and there is no rule for me to like or to upvote for those who do it. You should leave some time before you answer as a courtesy to fellow users. I downvoted because the question (in my opinion ) does not show any research effort.

Comment: @g24l: I don't see how waiting is courteous; that's what the technical limitation that I cannot _accept_ my own answer for 2 whole days is for -- you are welcome to continue posting whatever answer you like. As for your downvote reason... well, touché. My research effort went into the answer ;) _(Though I did indicate that I'd already perused the standard...)_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference to member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245404/reference-to-member-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `[C++11: 8.3.3/3]:` A pointer to member shall not point to a static
>   member of a class (9.4), a member with reference type, or “*cv* void.” [
>   *Note:* See also 5.3 and 5.5. The type “pointer to member” is distinct
>   from the type “pointer”, that is, a pointer to member is declared only
>   by the pointer to member declarator syntax, and never by the pointer
>   declarator syntax. **There is no “reference-to-member” type in C++.** *—end
>   note* ]

Comment: You just found this or knew it all along? :)

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: If I'm honest, I found it when halfway through writing the question. :)

Comment: Happens to me too. It's good to document such things too here at SO.

Comment: Somehow I don't believe that, maybe next quesion should be: does int main() require a return type?

Comment: @g24l: It would be closed as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-c).

Comment: @VJovic: Haha :P No, because the grammar is normative; the note merely Englishises it :)