# Why are member functions addressed this way?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why is there an ampersand when taking the address of a member function as opposed to a global function? I.e., why something like

```
std::bind(&MyClass::MemberFunction, ...);
```

when global functions would require

```
std::bind(GlobalFunction, ...);
```

?

Comment: `&` works on global functions.

Comment: But it works without it too.

Comment: You're asking why member function references don't exist - which is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21952386/why-doesnt-reference-to-member-exist-in-c

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`C` allowed implicit conversions from global function names to pointers to those functions. `C++` kept these implicit conversions for backwards compatibility reasons. `C` does not have member functions, and so there was no need to provide the implicit conversion in the case of member functions.

`C++` does not allow the implicit conversion in the cases where it was not forced to for compatibility with `C`, because it was felt that such conversions were confusing and possibly ambiguous, while providing few benefits.