# How do I differentiate an lvalue and rvalue member function pointer for overloaded functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I know that I can do this to differentiate a rvalue function name and an lvalue function pointer:

```
template <typename RET_TYPE, typename...ARGs>
void takeFunction(RET_TYPE(& function)(ARGs...))
{
    cout << "RValue function" << endl;
}

template <typename RET_TYPE, typename...ARGs>
void takeFunction(RET_TYPE(*& function)(ARGs...))
{
    cout << "LValue function" << endl;
}

void function()
{
}

void testFn()
{
    void(*f)() = function;
    takeFunction(function);
    takeFunction(f);
}
```

And I wish to do the same for member functions.  However, it doesn't seem to translate:

```
struct S;
void takeMemberFunction(void(S::&function)()) // error C2589: '&' : illegal token on right side of '::'
{
    cout << "RValue member function" << endl;
}

void takeMemberFunction(void(S::*&function)())
{
    cout << "LValue member function" << endl;
}

struct S
{
    void memberFunction()
    {
    }
};

void testMemberFn()
{
    void(S::*mf)() = &S::memberFunction;
    takeMemberFunction(S::memberFunction);
    takeMemberFunction(mf);
}
```

Why?

An alternative I know is to do this for regular functions:

```
void takeFunction(void(*&& function)())
{
    cout << "RValue function" << endl;
}

void takeFunction(void(*& function)())
{
    cout << "LValue function" << endl;
}

void function()
{
}

void testFn()
{
    void(*f)() = function;
    takeFunction(&function);
    takeFunction(f);
}
```

Which does translate to member functions:

```
struct S;
void takeMemberFunction(void(S::*&&function)())
{
    cout << "RValue member function" << endl;
}

void takeMemberFunction(void(S::*&function)())
{
    cout << "LValue member function" << endl;
}

struct S
{
    void memberFunction()
    {
    }
};

void testMemberFn()
{
    void(S::*mf)() = &S::memberFunction;
    takeMemberFunction(&S::memberFunction); // error C2664: 'void takeMemberFunction(void (__thiscall S::* &)(void))' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'void (__thiscall S::* )(void)' to 'void (__thiscall S::* &)(void)'
    takeMemberFunction(mf);
}
```

But I would like to know the discrepancy for my first example not translating.

Comment: _"this doesn't work"_ :(

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit: Huh? Not a useful comment.

Comment: Actually it is if you read it as "'this doesn't work' is not a useful problem description". The hope was to push you into improving it without going into explaining the obvious!

Comment: Since when are function names rvalues?

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit, not really.  I was just cleaning it up, regardless of your comment.

Comment: @T.C. well, I don't know what else they would be.

Comment: @Adrian: Next time please post the question its completed form the first time around.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit, like you don't make mistakes. Check out what you wrote. ^^ :D  We write and we rewrite to try and make it clearer, there's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: They are lvalues and always have been. There are no rvalues of function type.

Comment: @T.C., you can assign to an lvalue, you cannot assign to a function name.  Thus it is an rvalue (or a prvalue if you go outside of the definitions of just lvalue and rvalue).  QED

Comment: By your logic, given `const int i = 5;` `i` would be an rvalue. Have you actually read the standard?

Comment: @T.C. That's an interesting case.  `i` was on the left hand side at one point, so it *might* be considered to be an lvalue at that point.  But after that, I think it *would* be considered an rvalue.  I've read parts of the standard, though usually not directly.  Say, like in [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3601748/1366368) where it has been quoted.  I take it you've read all of the language laws and understand them 100%?

Comment: If you actually read that [basic.lval] quote, you'd see that "An lvalue [...] designates a function or an object." Also, [conv.fptr]/p1: "An lvalue of function type T can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T.” The result is a pointer to the function." [expr.prim.general]/p8: "An *identifier* is an *id-expression* provided it has been suitably declared (Clause 7). [...] The type of the expression is the type of the identifier. The result is the entity denoted by the identifier. **The result is an lvalue if the entity is a function**, variable, or data member and a prvalue otherwise."

Comment: @T.C., I'll have to mull that over and look over the standard a little.  However, how do you think I should have worded the question then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing this is a Visual C++ bug, as the following code (basically what you have in your question) [compiles for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bef186b67063134) on both gcc and clang, and I see no reason to expect it not to:

```
struct S;

void bar(void (S::*& f)() ) {
    std::cout << "lvalue" << std::endl;
}
void bar(void (S::*&& p)() ) {
    std::cout << "rvalue" << std::endl;
}

struct S {
    void foo() { }  
};

int main() {
    void (S::*f)();

    bar(f);        // prints lvalue
    bar(&S::foo);  // prints rvalue
}
```

For the other part of your question, see [Why doesn't reference-to-member exist in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21952386/2069064).

Comment: @Angew Yep, included my own link too that uses both compilers. I believe the linked question does a good job of addressing that other part.

Comment: Yes, it does. It just wasn't there when I made the comment :-)

Comment: @Angew You're just too speedy, man. Beat me by like 10 seconds :) (on the proof part I mean, the other part I added in response to your comment)

Comment: It isn't because it isn't.  Disappointing and I think inconsistent with how regular functions are parsed. Ah well. :/

Comment: BTW, it's not a bug in the compiler.  It was caused by a typo.

Comment: @Adrian Ahhh... `takeeMemberFunction`... I see it now.