# Can a shared pointer call a function template argument

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr, function-templates

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30930350/why-member-functions-cant-be-used-as-template-arguments) answered my original question: how can I can I template on a member function?

The answer has the code:

```
struct Foo {
    void Bar() { // do something
    }
};
template <typename TOwner, void(TOwner::*func)()>
void Call(TOwner *p) {
    (p->*func)();
}
int main() {
    Foo a;
    Call<Foo, &Foo::Bar>(&a);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to accomplish the same thing with shared pointers.  I found that this does NOT work:

```
template <typename TOwner, void(TOwner::*func)()>
void Call(std::shared_ptr<TOwner> p) {
    (p->*func)();
}
```

However, this works

```
template <typename TOwner, void(TOwner::*func)()>
void Call(std::shared_ptr<TOwner> p) {
    (p.get()->*func)();
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think `((*p).*func)()` is slightly easier on the eye. (And works with raw pointers, as well.)

Answer (score 3):

Let me try to address the "Is there a better way to accomplish this?" part of the question: If you can use C++17, there is [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) which nicely handles pointer to member functions and smart pointers:

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

auto a = std::make_shared<Foo>();

std::invoke(&Foo::Bar, a); // Ok: pass the shared_ptr itself
std::invoke(&Foo::Bar, *a); // Also ok: pass a reference to the pointee
```

`std::invoke` can replace the `Call` function template in this case, still accepting arbitrary member function pointers.