# Define generic member function as template parameter without redundant member signature as parameter

Tags: templates, c++17, variadic-templates, member, template-argument-deduction

I try to write a generic member `Delegate` function (based on this cool answer [generic member function pointer as a template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779105/generic-member-function-pointer-as-a-template-parameter)):

```cpp
template <typename T, T>
class Delegate {};

template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args, R (T::*TMember)(Args...)>
class Delegate<R (T::*)(Args...), TMember> {
 public:
  Delegate(T &obj) : obj_{obj} {}

  R operator()(Args &&... args) const noexcept(
      noexcept((obj_.*TMember)(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) {
    return (obj_.*TMember)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

 private:
  T &obj_;
};

template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args, R (T::*TMember)(Args...) const>
class Delegate<R (T::*)(Args...) const, TMember> {
 public:
  Delegate(const T &obj) : obj_{obj} {}

  R operator()(Args &&... args) const noexcept(
      noexcept((obj_.*TMember)(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) {
    return (obj_.*TMember)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

 private:
  const T &obj_;
};

struct Foo {
  int Bar(int a, int b) noexcept { return a + b; }

  int ConstBar(int a, int b) const noexcept { return a + b; }
};

int main() {
  Foo obj;
  auto add = Delegate<int (Foo::*)(int, int), &Foo::Bar>(obj);

  std::cout << add(1, 2) << std::endl;  // 3

  const Foo const_obj;
  auto const_add =
      Delegate<int (Foo::*)(int, int) const, &Foo::ConstBar>(const_obj);

  std::cout << const_add(3, 4) << std::endl; // 7

  return 0;
}
```

So, the questions are:

1. Can i somehow omit fuzzy pointer to member in `Delegate` instantiation, like this: `Delegate<Foo::Bar>(obj)`?
2. I'm lazy, and specifying member signature two times looks too hard for me. Can we somehow deduce template signature based on single template argument, so `Delegate<int (Foo::*)(int, int), &Foo::Bar>(obj)` becomes `Delegate<&Foo::Bar>(obj)`?
3. To write generic code i need to propagate `noexcept` specifier from member to `Delegate`'s `operator()` via `noexcept(noexcept((obj_.*TMember)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))`. May `noexcept` specifier be derived from `return` body itself, instead of specifying body both times?
4. I need to specialize both versions - `const` and non-`const` ones. May compiler do this for me? What about `volatile` / `const volatile` specializations, should i copy the same code again and again?

If smth is impossible, please, describe why, or, at least, where can i read about :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Can i somehow omit fuzzy pointer to member in Delegate instantiation, like this: Delegate(obj)?

According [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7245602/6022656)... I suppose the answer is "no".

> 2. I'm lazy, and specifying member signature two times looks too hard for me. Can we somehow deduce template signature based on single template argument, so Delegate(obj) becomes Delegate<&Foo::Bar>(obj)?

You tagged C++17, so... yes: you can use `auto`

```
template <auto>
class Delegate
 { };

template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args,
          R (T::*TMember)(Args...)>
class Delegate<TMember>

// ...

template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args,
          R (T::*TMember)(Args...) const>
class Delegate<TMember>

// ...


   // ...    

   auto add = Delegate<&Foo::Bar>(obj);

   // ...

   auto const_add =
      Delegate<&Foo::ConstBar>(const_obj);
```

> 4. I need to specialize both versions - const and non-const ones. May compiler do this for me? What about volatile / const volatile specializations, should i copy the same code again and again?

Maybe adding a level of indirection?

I mean... if you create a base class for `Delegate` as follows

```
template <auto TMember, typename T, typename R, typename ... Args>
class DelegateBase
 {
   public:
      DelegateBase (T & obj) : obj_{obj}
       { }

      R operator() (Args &&... args) const
         noexcept
         (noexcept((std::declval<T>().*TMember)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)))
       { return (obj_.*TMember)(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

   private:
      T & obj_;
 };
```

you can write `Delegate` using `DelegateBase`

```
template <auto>
class Delegate
 { };

template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args,
          R (T::*TMember)(Args...)>
class Delegate<TMember>
   : public DelegateBase<TMember, T, R, Args...>
 { using DelegateBase<TMember, T, R, Args...>::DelegateBase; };

template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args,
          R (T::*TMember)(Args...) const>
class Delegate<TMember>
   : public DelegateBase<TMember, T const, R, Args...>
 { using DelegateBase<TMember, T const, R, Args...>::DelegateBase; };
```

I suppose you can add a couple of `volatile`/`const volatile` specializations.

---

Off Topic: if you want to use perfect forwarding, you have to use forwarding references, not r-value references.

I mean... you can't use perfect forwarding in your `operator()`

```
  R operator()(Args &&... args) const noexcept(
      noexcept((obj_.*TMember)(std::forward<Args>(args)...))) {
    return (obj_.*TMember)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  } // ....................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ wrong
```

because the `Args...` pack is a variadic parameter of the class, not of the operator; so in `operator()`, the `Args && ... args` are r-value references (so `std::move`).

If you want to use perfect forwarding, you have to use template parameters of the `operator()` itself, so

```
  template <typename ... As>
  R operator()(As &&... args) const noexcept(
      noexcept((obj_.*TMember)(std::forward<As>(args)...))) {
    return (obj_.*TMember)(std::forward<As>(args)...);
  } // ....................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ok
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks exactly as i want. 
Was screwed by Visual Studio 2019 intellisense in a CMake project.

Comment: Good solution for specializations copy-past problem!
May be you also know how to skip copy-paste body in `noexcept` and remove noisy pointer to member in `Delegate` instantiation?

Comment: @dimhotepus - not at the moment; but I'm thinking about 1 and 3.

Comment: @dimhotepus - added an answer ("no") to point 1; I suppose the answer is "no" also for point 3 but I'm not sure.

Comment: @dimhotepus - added an off topic about perfect forwarding; hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for all answers! Especially for perfect forwarding. 

Unfortunately, i'm stuck with SFINAE and partial specialization for `volatile` / `const volatile`. I've tried smth like this:
 `, std::enable_if_t<std::is_volatile_v<T>, R> (T::*TMember)(Args...)>
class Delegate<TMember> : public DelegateBase<TMember, volatile T, R, Args...> {
  using DelegateBase<TMember, volatile T, R, Args...>::DelegateBase;
};`
but it didn't help. Also i can't define additional template parameter with `std::enable_if`, as partial template specialization disallows default parameter.